# Term similar to nomenclature, but applying more broadly to systems of representation in general not just naming?

Tags: vocabulary

What's an appropriate term to use when discussing conventions for representing concepts in an academic field (whether that be STEM e.g. formatting equations.  English e.g. breaking down grammar or, Music e.g. sheet music,).

Nomenclature refers only to names for concepts or things, I'm looking for something more broad.

Jargon's similar to nomenclature but with a negative connotation, and again applies only to words and phrases.

Comment: Did you look for synonyms of 'nomenclature'? Also, broader in what way?

Comment: Nomenclature refers to naming only, whereas the word I'm looking for applies to any generally agreed way of representing concepts (formal notation systems etc.)

Comment: For example, if subject, verb, object, adverbial, phrase etc. fall under nomenclature, what I'm looking for would describe the generally agreed upon way of breaking down a sentence into these components, and representing that breakdown (the general conventions of conceptual representation rather than just the conventions of which nouns to use for different things)

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: notation, maybe?

Comment: "Terminology" or "Concepts and wording" ?

Comment: @Graffito that only really refers to vocabulary, it wouldn't apply to music notation or mathematical equations for example

Answer (score 2):

You could call them *'schemata'* - from [**'schema'**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/schema):

> A representation of a plan or theory in the form of an outline or model: *a schema of scientific reasoning* (-- oxforddictionaries.com)